# Attribute error with .docx document no attribute 'xpath'

Tags: python, xpath, ms-word, docx, python-docx

```
from docx import *
document = Document(r'filepath.docx')
words = document.xpath('//w:r', namespaces=document.nsmap)
WPML_URI = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
tag_rPr = WPML_URI + 'rPr'
tag_highlight = WPML_URI + 'highlight'
tag_val = WPML_URI + 'val'
tag_t = WPML_URI + 't'
for word in words:
    for rPr in word.findall(tag_rPr):
        high = rPr.findall(tag_highlight)
        for hi in high:
            if hi.attribute[tag_val] == 'yellow':
                print(word.find(tag_t).text.encode('utf-8').lower())
```

this code in theory should get the document text and then find the highlighted text in yellow, but my problem is at the start i run the code as is, and i get 
`AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'xpath'` 
as the error message. its problem is apparently with 
`words = document.xpath('//w:r', namespaces=document.nsmap)`
 and I don't know how to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PirateNinjas is right on. The `Document` object does not subclass `lxml.etree._Element` and so does not have the `.xpath()` method. This is what `AttributeError` indicates; each method on an object is an attribute (just like an instance variable is) and if one with the name you ask for isn't there, you get this error.

However, `Document._element` *does* subclass `_Element` and may work for you. At least it won't give you this error and should move you further in the right direction. This code should give you all the `<w:r>` elements in the main story of the document (i.e. document body, but not headers, footnotes, etc.):

```
rs = document._element.xpath("//w:r")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, I'm new to coding so I dont fully understand how to use Document._element to give me the paragraphs that i can use?

Comment: Apologies @Hxxerre, I had accidentally left that out of the code, it should be: `rs = document._element.xpath("//w:r")`. I've updated that in the code example.

Comment: thanks again for your help, that did work but now there is another error involving ' if hi.attribute[tag_val] == 'yellow': ' the error is anAttributeError, it says 'AttributeError: 'CT_Higlight ' object has no attribute 'attribute' ' from my understanding is that its not picking anything up to look for?

Comment: Welcome StackOverflow Hxxerre, and glad you got past your initial problem. Don't neglect to accept this answer if it answered your initial question, as stated. Please post any follow-up questions separately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to do something to the `docx.Document` that isn't allowed. If you look [here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.document.Document) you can see the documentation for this and `.xpath` does not exist for `Document`.

If you need the words,you can probably get them via the `Document.paragraph` method - also in the docs linked.

Answer (score 0):

```
from docx import *
document = Document('xyz.docx')
words = document._element.xpath('//w:r')
WPML_URI = "{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}"
tag_rPr = WPML_URI + 'rPr'
tag_highlight = WPML_URI + 'highlight'
tag_val = WPML_URI + 'val'
tag_t = WPML_URI + 't'
for word in words:
    for rPr in word.findall(tag_rPr):
        high=rPr.findall(tag_highlight)
        for hi in high:
            if hi.attrib[tag_val] in ['yellow','blue','green']:
                 print(word.find(tag_t).text.encode('utf-8'))
```

If you want to extract, let's say yellow colored text, use this line of code:

```
if hi.attrib[tag_val] == 'yellow':
```